# background sky of a photo: removing the darker color

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I am new here! So this is a part of a photo I took at Washington Monument. As you can see the left side has become slightly darker. Is there any way to fix it? Thanks. Sorry for this unusually long photo. [image]

Answer (score 1):

Rough fix: copy image, lighten copy, give the copy layer a mask, paint to blend nicely using a huge and soft brush.